# Using C# in SSIS to connect to a SharePoint list

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, sharepoint-2013, etl

I need to connect to a SharePoint list to extract data.

I keep finding solutions to download a GUI control, but here's my problem...

I can't connect to the SP site in DEV to use the GUI. So my plan was to use a script component source, so that I can just handle the connection and expected columns there.

Can someone provide a basic solution or point me in the proper direction.

I am going to try and implement this:

- [How to: Return List Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms429658(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Blocked again from leaving DEV environment while setting up web service connection

Comment: I Provided an answer that contains helpful links, by i think you should try using ODATA components to achieve this instead of Script Component. In addition, can you provide the List link and the exception thrown to get more help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many methods to import Sharepoint Lists:

## Using ODATA Source

You can use ODATA Source component to access to the Sharepoint Lists

- [Using the SSIS OData Source Connector with SharePoint Online](https://sharepointsolutiontips.blogspot.com/2016/07/using-ssis-odata-source-connector-with.html)
- [Using the OData Source in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3220/using-the-odata-source-in-sql-server-integration-services/)
- [Connecting to SharePoint from SSIS using OData Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259319/connecting-to-sharepoint-from-ssis-using-odata-source)

## Using Sharepoint Source

YOU have to [Download the SSIS Sharepoint components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh368261.aspx).

You can find many step by step articles that you can refer to them:

- [How To Use a SharePoint List as a Data Source in your SSIS Package.](https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2011/06/how-to-use-a-sharepoint-list-as-a-data-source-in-your-ssis-package/)
- [Accessing SharePoint Lists with SQL Server Integration Services SSIS 2005](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1733/accessing-sharepoint-lists-with-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-2005/)
- [Microsoft SQL Server Community Samples: Integration Services](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sqlsrvintegrationsrv)

## Third Party Components

- [KingswaySoft SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft SharePoint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KingswaySoft.SSISIntegrationToolkitforMicrosoftSharePoint)
- [AxioWorks SQList](http://www.axioworks.com/sqlist/?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_pulse_read%3BhTS8%2FvDSRQ%2BUYgjUeovuZQ%3D%3D)

Comment: The problem I am going to have with the ODATA Source is that I don't have connectivity in my DEV environment to go through the GUI driven menus. Only PROD will have access to the SharePoint site.

Comment: I don't think you can do this if you don't have connectivity with any of these methods.