# SSIS: How Do I set up an oData Source connection to a SharePoint document?

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, odata

Using SSIS, I have to pick up files from a SharePoint site that a client is placing there. It's two files and the client will simply overwrite the files every time they need new data processed. The name of the files are Current Pathways.xlsx and Prior Pathways.xlsx. The SharePoint directory they are being placed in is

https://jeffersonkyschools.sharepoint.com/sites/CTE/REPORTS/Forms/AllItems.aspx

I'm trying to use an oData source connection to pick up the files, but all the instructions I'm finding are specifically for picking up lists, not documents.  Does anybody have any experience picking up SharePoint documents for an SSIS project?

**UPDATE:**
I have kind of taken a baby step forward, I'm now able to connect to one of the files by using the following:

Service document location: https://jeffersonkyschools.sharepoint.com/sites/CTE/TEDS
Authentication Type: Microsoft Online Services

User Name: (work email)

Password: (pwd)

My new issue is that apparently it's expecting this file to be an xml formatted file, but it's an excel file. This is starting to feel hopeless.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Connecting to SharePoint from SSIS using OData Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259319/connecting-to-sharepoint-from-ssis-using-odata-source)

OData in SSIS is typically used for **SharePoint lists**, *not files*.

Use the REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest

Heres an example to get you started (using jQuery to send an AJAX request): https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138135/get-all-files-and-folders-in-one-call

```
var folderUrl = '/sites/CTE/REPORTS';
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderUrl + "')/Files";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
            console.log("File: " + item.Name);
        });
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("Error: " + data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! This looks like what I need to download the file, but I'm still having an issue connecting to the SharePoint site, which requires a user id and password. I've tried HTTP Connection manager and it returns a status of "403: Forbidden". I've run out of ideas of how to connect to the site at this point :(

Comment: Hi Jimmy take a look at this related issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1345819/basic-authentication-to-sharepoint-2019-through-re

Also refer to this MSFT guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/connect-to-sharepoint
Try using an access token: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321532/sharepoint-rest-api-how-to-get-access-token
Otherwise as a last resort, enable basic authentication in the IIS settings.